# Excel - Conditional Formmating Formula based on two conditions

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[image]
My current formula

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*")*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A1)>1)
```

Highlights the EE Number cells if a specific employee number has more than one Job title and if one of those job titles contains the word "Manager". How would I change it so it highlights the EE Number cells if a specific employee number has more than one job title with one of them containing the word "manager" and another containing the word "cashier". I tried changing my formula to this:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*")*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*cashier*")>1)
```

but it gives me the error `you have entered too many arguments for this function` . Is this possible to do in conditional formatting?

Comment: Did you mean to use `COUNTIFS` for the second statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIF` can only take 2 parameters. You need to use `COUNTIFS`, like in the first part of your currently working formula. What you actually can do is add the cashier part right after the manager part:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*",$D$2:$D$11,"*cashier*")*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A1)>1)
```

The above will highlight instances where the job name contains both `manager` **and** `cashier` at the same time. If you want to highlight instances where the job name contains either `manager` **or** `cashier` **or both**, then you can try:

```
=(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*cashier*"))*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A1)>1)
```

**EDIT:** Overlooked `manager` on at least one row **and** `cashier` on a different row, which would lead to:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*")*COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*cashier*")*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A1)>1)
```

Comment: It needs to be more than one job name though. One containing manager and one containing cashier. So in my example, EE number 12 will be highlighted because it has a manger job name and a cashier job name.

Comment: @CameronCole Ah, I didn't consider that other possibility (sorry about that). In that case, it should work if you change the `+` in the second formula to a `*`.

Comment: No problem at all, worked like a charm! thanks a ton!